# NFS Network path not found

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, nfs

I did setup a nfs share on my debian 7 server and been trying to mount it on a windows 7 machine.

I've tried the following:

```
C:\Users\David>mount \\192.168.178.240\backups Y:
Network Error - 53

Type 'NET HELPMSG 53' for more information.


C:\Users\David>mount 192.168.178.240:/backups Y:
Network Error - 53

Type 'NET HELPMSG 53' for more information.
```

When I run `NET HELPMSG 53` it tells me that the network path was not found.

```
C:\Users\David>showmount -e 192.168.178.240
Exports list on 192.168.178.240:
/backups                           192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0
```

As you can see it **does** exists. The IP address of the windows 7 machine is 192.168.137.252 so this is in the right subnet.

/etc/exports is as following:

```
root@debiansrv:~# grep backups /etc/exports
/backups 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0(rw)
```

Comment: tried the same as above on a windows server 2008 R2 (IP: 192.168.178.230). Same error(s)

Comment: what happens if you try to use `net use` instead of `mount`?

Comment: It gives the same error

Comment: Is SMB sharing (also) enabled on the Samba share?  What happens if you try to connect to it using Tools->Map Network Drive from within Windows Explorer?

Comment: Well I'm settings up a NFS share, not a Samba share?
When I try to map it as a network drive it gives the same error.

Comment: Found the solution. besides the rw option I had to add "insecure"

Comment: Nice to hear!  You should expand that solution a little and add it as an answer for future visitors (it's allowed :) ).

Comment: Will try. English is not my native language as you might have noticed.. Also had to map the uid and gid from the anonymous user to make the write and read permissions work.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting a "*" instead of specifying the drive name.

Error 53 also return when it cannot allocate the drive name as well.

Also, mount exactly as the showmount -e output show, eg:

if in your export say /home as the export, do not mount /home/[something], window wont understand.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I found at [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/533887/network-error-53-while-trying-to-mount-nfs-share-in-windows-server-2008-clie)

```
NFS server has an option of working in insecure mode (Allowing higher incoming port numbers). Windows NFS client often uses higher port numbers. You can enable this option by adding an option to the share Example: /share *(insecure,rw)

You can also try installing Windows services for UNIX package which contains a nfs client. You can try to connect the nfs server using this utility and cross check again. You can download the package from the following link http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/e...displayLang=en
```

I changed the /etc/exports according to it (by adding the insecure option) and it work